# How to subtract cell with the help of VLOOKUP or any other function/formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

how can I subtract current day data from previous day data with in a same month in complete worksheet, for example to get the value in cell N9 that is cell M9-P12 & cell N8 that is M8-M9, how can I get the value automatically

[image]

Comment: How about `=M9-IF(ISTEXT(M11),INDEX($M$12:$U$12,MATCH(M$2,$M$10:$U$10,0)),M10)` at `N9`?

Comment: Thanx for the reply, and sir can use this formula in N8 N7 N6...... and so on.

Comment: and sir if I want to use this code in coloumn  P & S then which location i have to change in formula written by you. Thnx again Best Regards.

Comment: Have you copied the formula from`N9` to `P9` and `S9` and dragged the formula up?

Comment: sir how can i get the change in % in coloum O R and U

Comment: `=100-(IF(ISTEXT(M11),INDEX($M$12:$U$12,MATCH(M$2,$M$10:$U$10,0)),M10)/M9*100)` in `O9`, same logic.

Comment: sir in O9 instead of 3 % i am getting 258%. currently i am using =(M9-P12)/P12 this formula.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFjJq.jpg